# Google app script getting a value from a cell in sheets using row and column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to use row and column to access a cell in google script on sheets.

Running the following in a google sheet cell

```
function prHello() {
  var row = 1;
  var col = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // Passing only two arguments returns a "range" with a single cell.
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);
  var value = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  var value1 = range.getValue();
  var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col).getValue();

  return "value="+value+' value1='+value1+' value2='+value2+' done' ;
}
```

I get *value= value1= value2=2 done* with the table of
| A | B |
| --| --|
1| 1 | 2 |
2| 3 | 4 |

I thought it should return *value=2 value1=2 value2=2 done*

Comment: I think that if your `| 1| 1 |` it the 1st row, `"value="+value+' value1='+value1+' value2='+value2+' done'` returns `value=1 value1=1 value2=1 done`. But you say `I get value= value1= value2=2 done with the table of | A | B | | --| --| 1| 1 | 2 | 2| 3 | 4 |`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script or your table. How about this? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Pay attention to the sheet you are working with. Is it the 1-st one in the spreadsheet? Is it active when the script runs? Probably you mixed different sheets data.

Comment: It is multi-sheet. The active sheet is sheet3.  Cell A1 contains 1, cell B1 contains 2, cell A2 contains 3, cell B2 contains 4.  The value2 is retreived correctly.  If B1 value is changed it is seen in the cell that this function runs in (D6).

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheets()[0];//first sheet in the list of sheets
  Logger.log(sh1.getRange("B1").getValue())
  const  sh2 = ss.getActiveSheet();//the sheet you have selected
  Logger.log(sh2.getRange("B1").getValue())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am trying to use row and column not A1 notation.  The data loops that are done are easier to me using row and column. Why does value2 work and the others do not?